# How do i store output of this function to somewhere

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to scrape url for elements to have them be outputted to a file but it doesn't seem to work -The function runs fine to have them printed

```
def get_price():
    page = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
    while True:
        try:
            product_title = soup.find("span",{'id': "productTitle"}).text.strip()
            #price = float((soup.find("span",{'class': "a-offscreen"}).text.split("₹")[1]).replace(',',""))
            f = open("Textfile.txt", "w")
            f.write(product_title)
            f.close()
            break
        except AttributeError:
            get_price()
            break
    
get_price()
```

Comment: Where do you want to store the output?

Comment: The most simple way: You can open a textfile, convert output to string and write that output into the textfile.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar I want to be able to store them in a textfile..

Comment: @romancedawn sorry, i think i'm trying to do what you're suggesting in the above code or maybe i'm misunderstanding

Comment: remove the excpet pat and tell us what error are u getting

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar it will throw an AttributeError of NoneType, because I'm trying to scrape from Amazon, and it gets detected 3 times of 5 more or less

Comment: so isn't the content stored in `Textfile.txt` currently?

Comment: nope...it is blank..it is where i want to write the output of my function

Comment: Did you try find_all instead of find? find_all returns a list, after that you can write elements of that list

Comment: i fixed it, turns out the file was actually getting created and output being stored in it, it’s just that file was not getting created in the same directory as the python file..thanks for all your help